# "Login failed for user..." when I log on to my online SQL Server using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, sql-authentication

I have a database on a hosting server that I try to connect using C# `SqlConnection` class. I can log on to the server through SQL Server Management Studio using SQL Server authentication without problem.

My initiation code looks like this:

```
public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

public Constructor() {
    ConnectionString = @"Data source=SQL6002.site4now.net;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;User Id=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword;";
}
```

where database name, user name and passwords are replaced with the proper values. The connection code looks like:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    ...
}
```

This code works when I'm using a local db connection string. However, when I'm using the connection string above I get the error

> An error has occurred. Login failed for user 'IFC\WINxxxx$'.
>
> ExceptionType: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   StackTrace
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, etc. etc.

where x in the user name are numbers. Also, this isn't the user name I use in the connection string.

I have tried to add trusted_connection=true, and also integrated security=true without success.

When I log on to the server via SQL Server Management Studio and open properties in Security -> Logins -> MyUserName, I note that the password does not have the same length as the one I use to log on to SSMS with. I do not have permission to change it through SSMS, only through the host, smarterasp.net.

Any inputs are very welcome!

Comment: The error is telling you that it thinks the user is `IFC\\WINxxxx$`, not `MyUserName` as in your connection string above.  That looks an awful lot like it's using integrated authentication (i.e. Windows Auth) and not a SQL login.

Comment: `Trusted_Connection=True;` and `integrated security=true` - these are telling the server to use Windows Authentication, which is what you **don't** want,

Comment: Stuartd : You need windows credentials to connect between two PC.  the two PC need to be in the same group to complete a connection with or without a SQL.  If you do not use windows credentials then you have Guest Privileges and then you have to allow Guest access to the database.

Comment: @jdweng not sure I understand, what 2 PCs are these? What group? If the Sql Server is accepting connections over tcp using Sql Server auth, then what 2 PCs are connecting? I'm sure I'm just missing something, is it something to do with the hosting? And why can OP connect from SSMS?

Comment: SSMS is probably using a window credential.  The 2 PCs are the local PC where c# application is running and SQL Server PC.  Windows require authorization for remote connections.  So a User Group is required in the User Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. I moved the credentials to an instance of SqlCredentials, as

```
var credentials = new SqlCredentials(userName, password);
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString, credentials){
    con.Open();
}
```

where password is a readonly SecureString(). That did the trick!